# How can I limit the number of error messsages displayed after compiling a C++ program?

Tags: compiling, error-handling, g++

I am compiling a C++ program with `g++` and each time get a huge number of errors, forcing me to scroll up every time I want to view the first (and most relevant) error. I am wondering if there is an option when I am compiling the program that would allow me to limit the number of error messages displayed in the terminal.

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: It seems that you are asking about IDE.

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `compiling-command | head --lines 32` to output first 32 lines from `compiling-command` output.
You can also use `compiling-command | grep "Text to search" | head --lines 32` to display first 32 finds of "Text to search".

Disabling `-Wall` option with gcc will not output as many errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use option `-fmax-errors=1` to set the number of errors to 1 and so on. The default 0 is infinite. The [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) option applies to `g++`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Use compiler options to set a limit on the number of error messages before the compiler just gives up completely, as in another answer.
- Use `head`, remembering that error messages *are sent to standard error* of course.  Or use one of the *many* tools floating around that post-process GCC output.  Also remember that with modern versions of GCC that have adopted the clang model a single error can span several lines, so low line counts for `head` might not be very useful at all.
- Use a paginator such as `pager`, `pg`, `more`, or `less`, again remembering that error messages *are sent to standard error*.
- Run the compilation command in a `:terminal` within NeoVIM, which provides quite a lot of scrollback, and of course all of the usual VIM navigation key sequences for quickly going to the top of the output and searching.
- Integrate with your text editor.

The latter is the most interesting option.  It comes in at least two flavours:

- Write the standard output+standard error of the compiler to a file and tell your text editor to treat it as an *errors file*.  With Vim and NeoVIM this is done with

  ```
  vim -q errors_file
  ```

  and

  ```
  nvim -q errors_file
  ```

  where you can substitute the name of your choosing for `errors_file` of course.

  This will open the text editor with the errors file loaded into the quickfix buffer, and the file for the first error or warning message opened and positioned at the line number (and column) of that error.
- Run the compiler from within one's text editor.  With Vim and NeoVIM if one has a makefile one can invoke it with the `:make` command, and VIM/NeoVIM will put the error output from running `make` into a quickfix list, again automatically positioning at the file, line, and column of the first error or warning message.

With both of these, one can of course move from the location of one warning/error to the next using `:cnext` and the various other Vim/NeoVIM quickfix list navigation commands listed at `:help :cc`.  Note that there's no reason to limit the number of errors with these mechanisms, and there are Vim/NeoVIM commands to return to the position of the current message, or go back to the position of the first message.

With the latter specifically, one can also run `:make` multiple times and change back and forth between older and newer error lists using `:colder` and `:cnewer`.  (One can additionally change `:make` to run something other than `make`, using `set makeprg`, more of which in the VIM/NeoVIM manual.)

One can do similar things with emacs.